# User suddenly logged in as another user

Tags: 7, users

I face new problem in my site, we have reports from users that when they are surfing our site with their account, suddenly logged in as another user and continue surfing site as it.

I searched all modules for below patterns to find where global $user changed by mistake but found nothing.

```
$user->uid = 
$user = 
->uid =
```

Is there any suggestion about this issue?

Comment: perhaps the session information is becoming corrupted - do you know what the user was doing just before the 'switch'?

Comment: how "session information is becoming corrupted"? They do normal tasks like reading news, submitting comments and ...

Comment: no clue... maybe a module is causing it, maybe custom code - could be anything.

Comment: What modules do you have running? Can you copy the output of `drush pml` to the question space? That would really help people see what you're running.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that there is developer mistake here, we have something like  you guested,a global `$user` information  overwrite by developer code,I suggest you found when this happened,when a comment submit?when a specified form submit and .... ? 
I think in custom module your developer first  write `global $user;` and in continue define $user variable,I suggest you search for `global $user` then look at afterwards codes.